Powershell script does not execute on SQL Server job
I get a zip file that includes a database backup from our customer that needs to be restored on our server on a regular basis. The restore is done on an staging server, the data is than processed further to import it to production. Because the Zip file has a timestamp in the file name, we need to adapt our existing script for using wildcards. And here does the problem start. When I execute the powsershell script
if(Test-Path -Path \\VM-NTM-DATA01\<Customer>\Sample*.zip){
    Expand-Archive '\\VM-NTM-DATA01\<Customer>\Sample*.zip' -DestinationPath 'D:\TM5\<Customer>' -Force
}
else{
    Write-Error "The directory was empty!" -EA Stop
}

directly in a PS console, it runs just fine. But as soon as I add the code to a SQL Server Agent Jop step I get the following error message:
Executed as user: <DOMAIN>\agent. A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'if(Test-Path -Path \\VM-NTM-DATA01\<Customer>\Sample*.zip){ '. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Invalid Path: '\\VM-NTM-DATA01\<Customer>'.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.  The step failed.

I've also tried to use the parameter -LiteralPath but it didn't work either (with the wildcard included).
Any ideas how I need to implement the path, so the script does execute in the SQL Job?

Does th SQL Agent service account have access to said path?

Yes the Agent has access to the path. If I enter the complete filename with the timestamp, the script executes also just fine. It struggels with the wild card

What version of SQL Server? Are you using a version where you can utilise NOSQLPS?

Yes, this seems to work now. Thanks for the hint!
